# Creating new firebase storage bucket with dynamic name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

We are trying to create a new storage bucket where its name would be dynamically created. The firebase web interface provides this capability. It appears as the admin sdk (node.js) does not.

This screen capture shows the web interface behaviour. As you hit "add bucket", a new unique bucket name is dynamically generated.

[image]

This feature could be useful in creating buckets dynamically without having the need to reuse/develop a mechanic to generate a unique names and also prevent using uids (which is usually not recommended).

Can anyone confirm our understanding is right? Any insight whether this will be release (or at least in preview) in the upcoming releases of the admin sdk?

The sdk should at least have feature parity with the web interface.

If not, I am willing to open a feature request with the Firebase team.

Comment: There are limits on the number of buckets that can be added to a project. If you're planning to create buckets dynamically into the hundreds or thousands, you're likely to have a bad time. You can use security rules to add read/write authz protection to a single bucket, which may be the easier way forward.

Comment: I don't think we are there yet. We only have 5 buckets. We really believe it is a limitation with the admin sdk (unless there is something we do not know).

Comment: If you only have 5 buckets, why do you need to create them programmatically? If you can describe your use case more, might be able to help point you in the right direction. This may eventually be possible with the Admin SDK FWIW.

Comment: We are only testing the capability so we know we are not hitting any limitation at this point and still was unable to make it work. Our use case is to store documents that belong either to organizations or users. Because orgs/users may have same filenames, we were thinking to either create dedicated buckets for orgs and for users. One option is to use the firestore id (this option works) but is not recommended. Thanks!

Comment: I would not recommend creating per-user buckets. Why is the firestore id not recommended? Namespacing object names is exactly the recommended way to do this, something like `orgs/{orgId}/{upload=**}` or `users/{userId}/{upload=**}`

Comment: When you say namespacing, it is still a bucket per id, one bucket with folders, a combination of the two? Thanks !

Comment: One bucket with folders (or maybe two buckets, one for orgs and one for users if there's a compelling reason to separate them). In general buckets are not really designed to be spun up on a per-customer/org basis unless you only plan to have < 100 customers of your app.